# How to navigate from app delegate class in window based iPhone application. How to write pushViewcontroller method in app delegate class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

- In my window base application I need to navigate to informationview from my appdelegate when i click on alert view button.
- alert view works with NSlog.
- But i need to push to the other view for this purpose i used

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:info animated:YES];

but it doesn't pushes. just nslog only prints

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //To count the number of launches
    NSInteger i = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"numOfCalls"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:i+1 forKey:@"numOfCalls"];
    NSLog(@"the number of active calls are %d",i%3);
    if(i%3==0 && i!=0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"you might prefer MedChart+"  message:@"Get it now for more options" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
             NSLog(@"canceled");

        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"Pushed to the information view ");

            InformationViewCotroller *info =  [[InformationViewCotroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"InformationViewCotroller" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:info animated:YES];     

        }

}
```

(dont consider 'i' values it is part of my logic).
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you verified that self.navigationController is a valid object?

Comment: Yes i already declared it in appdelegate.h

Comment: Have you printed its value in the debugger or in a log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Navigate to any viewController , set the RootController for your navigationController of appDelegate.
Add `navigationController.View` as subview of window.Then your root controller will be the first ViewController.from there you can push to any viewController.